# How to iterate over rows in BigQuery table quickly?

Tags: sql, performance, google-bigquery

I have a series of numbers and I want to flag rows where the id is more than certain percentage (let's say 1.5% but for simplicity I took 100% which is twice in the following example) over the id in previous flagged row.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `projectId.datasetId.tableId` AS
(SELECT id FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 100)) AS id ORDER BY id ASC);

ALTER TABLE `projectId.datasetId.tableId` ADD COLUMN flag INT64;

UPDATE `projectId.datasetId.tableId`
SET flag = 0
WHERE id IS NULL;

UPDATE `projectId.datasetId.tableId`
SET flag = 1
WHERE id=1; 


DECLARE x INT64 DEFAULT (SELECT id FROM `projectId.datasetId.tableId` WHERE id = 1);

FOR record in 
(SELECT * FROM `projectId.datasetId.tableId` ORDER BY id ASC)
DO
IF record.id/x = 2 THEN

    UPDATE `trusty-slate-338313.tick_history.test`
    SET flag = 1
    WHERE id=record.id;

    SET x = record.id;
END IF;
END FOR;
```

Ideally I would have converted this table to pandas dataframe and iterated rows but the issue is I have 2 Billion rows. So I need to find a faster way in BigQuery itself. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Not clear what you mean by `I want to flag rows where the id is more than certain percentage (let's say 1.5% but for simplicity I took 100% which is twice in the following example) over the id in previous flagged row` - Please elaborate, provide more details on logic!

Comment: Sorry if my question is not clear. I have stock price data at a minute level granularity. Each minute has a unique id. Let's say at id=1, price = $100, after 2340 minutes which is id=2340 the price is $101.5(1.5% delta). All. I want to flag the id 2340 then take $101.5 as new reference and find the next id where the price is (1 +/- 1.5%) of 101.5. which is $204.5255 or $99.9775. In the above example I didn't mention price and just did the same for ID column itself and took 100% which is twice. If I flag id=1, then 100% delta occurs at id=2,4,8 and so on. I want to flag these rows.

Comment: For a divide and conquer approach: How many rows do fullfill the 1.5% condition already to the line directly above? Thus this line will be flagged reagardless of the other lines above. The dataset is split at these lines and each piece can be analyzed in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Never ever cycle to every row in a dataset when using SQL!
Your Script compares the value of the id in previous row to the one in the current row. This can be done by the function `lag` without the `for` command.

```
Select *, price/price_old as change, price/price_old >= 1.1 as flag
FROM 
(
SELECT id, price, LAG(price) over ( ORDER BY id ASC) as price_old 
From Test.tableId
)
order by id
```

If you want to process only the flagged rows, please set a filter on the flag column and replace the `id` in the innerer select by `*` and save this table temporary somewhere to access by your python script.

Comment: I don't want change from the last id, I need change from the last flagged id

Comment: I changed the script, so that it looks for a change in the price field

Comment: This code checks the ratio of price with current row with the previous row. Please have a look at this question for better understanding. https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/3799/how-to-write-a-lp-mip-to-mark-the-items-in-a-time-series-list-after-a-fixed-delt